# Blocked by CORS policy error when i insert YouTube video in wordpress post

Tags: youtube-api

I am using wordpress and facing this issue on google search console and also my video is not indexing in google search console
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i am just want to answer step by step of my issue.